# Using solver SparseLU and getting error C2664

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I'm trying to use Eigen to solve a sparse linear system in c++, also I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

The lines of the code that is using Eigen are below:

```
        Eigen::VectorXd x(sizeM), b(sizeM);
        Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(sizeM, sizeM);
        Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index> > solver;
        // M is my coefficient array and B is my independent vector.
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++)
        {
            b(i) = B[i];
        }
        A.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(sizeM, 6));
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeM; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeM; j++)
            {
                if (M[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    A.insert(i,j) = M[i][j];
                }

            }
        }
        A.makeCompressed();
        // Compute the ordering permutation vector from the structural pattern of A.
        solver.analyzePattern(A);
        // Compute the numerical factorization .
        solver.factorize(A);
        //Use the factors to solve the linear system .
        x = solver.solve(b);
```

The code error is this:

```
c:\users\bruno\desktop\c++ apps\eigen\eigen\src\sparselu\sparselu.h(421): error C2664: 'void Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index>::operator ()<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int>>(const MatrixType &,Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1,-1,StorageIndex> &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1,-1,int>' to 'Eigen::PermutationMatrix<-1,-1,StorageIndex> &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            MatrixType=Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int>,
1>            StorageIndex=Eigen::Index
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            StorageIndex=Eigen::Index
1>        ]
1>c:\users\bruno\desktop\c++ apps\eigen\eigen\src\sparselu\sparselu.h(412): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int>,Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index>>::analyzePattern(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int> &)'
1>c:\users\bruno\desktop\c++ apps\project1\project1\main.cpp(386): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int>,Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index>>::analyzePattern(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int> &)' being compiled
1>c:\users\bruno\desktop\c++ apps\project1\project1\main.cpp(367): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int>,Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index>>' being compiled
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I'm new both to Eigen and C++, so I'm not completely sure where is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, write:

```
Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int> > solver;
```

or

```
Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor, Eigen::Index>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<Eigen::Index> > solver;
```

where `Eigen::ColMajor` is optional in the first case.

Explanation: The last template argument of `Eigen::SparseMatrix` defines the `StorageIndex`, which must be the same for `Eigen::COLAMDOrdering`. By default, this is `int` (32bit on most architectures), whereas `Eigen::Index` is a typedef for `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is 64bit on 64bit architectures.

Comment: Thank you chtz, your suggestion worked perfectly! 

I'm still getting used to this kind of complex program structure, MatLab is a lot easier in this aspect.